# QML change views on Click

Tags: c++, qt, qml

i'm working on a project with my team.
My job is to create a Gui with QML and C++ for an Embedded System.

I have for each View a qml file.

But now i want to navigate between them.
This mean when i'm clicking on a Button, the view should switch.
Every View will have a back button, so i could go back to my Main View.

Is this possible in qml?
If not i have to solve it with c++

Comment: You can do it with QT Stacked Widgets easily. Check this out, https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstackedwidget.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can create a class deriving from `QDeclarativeView` in C++ and use:

```
void setSource ( const QUrl & url )
```

to change the qml file that is currently displayed. You can than call this method multiple times when a button is clicked.

---

There is also a solution using QML only. Take a look at the [Loader](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html) element:

```
 import QtQuick 1.0
 Item {
   width: 200; height: 200

   Loader { id: pageLoader }

   MouseArea {
     anchors.fill: parent
     onClicked: pageLoader.source = "Page1.qml"
   }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks JuliusG for your answer, but i think with your version there should be in every View a Loader?
Or where the pageloader know that i mean it?

Comment: You do not need to add Loader to each file. Its enough to have a main qml with one Loader and you can change its contents each time a button is clicked in each view. To pass data from loaded view to main qml you can call a method of an object in the main.

Comment: Thanks i have tested it :)
But i think the QDeclarativeView should be right for me

Comment: Thanks a ton @JuliusG your comment saved my day

Answer (score 12):

Another option is to have a main qml where you instantiate those qml views, and you change between them using states.

```
Main {
  View1{id:viewid1}
  View2{id:viewid2}
  View3{id:viewid3}
  states: [
    State {
        name: ""
    },
    State {
        name: "view1"
        PropertyChanges {target: viewid1; state: "focused"}
    },
    State {
        name: "view2"
        PropertyChanges {target: viewid2; state: "focused"}
     ...
    }
  ]
}
```

The difference between these option and the one already presented is that this one is permanent, and the other charges your QML every time (which means parsing and instantiation...).

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)
But i used JuliusGs answer, but yours look well too

Comment: Another difference between this solution and @JuliusG 's solution is that this solution instantiates all the QML at startup while his solution only instantiates each QML page when the source gets changed. This could be helpful or harmful depending on your application needs.

Answer (score 7):

One more example

```
import QtQuick 2.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1
import QtQuick.Window 2.1

ApplicationWindow {
    title: qsTr("My super app")
    width: 640
    height: 480

    Button {
        id: settingsButton
        x: 370
        y: 0
        text: qsTr("Settings")
        /* just change `visible` property by click */
        onClicked: {
            statusView.visible     = false
            settingsView.visible   = true
        }
    }

    Button {
        id: statusButton
        x: 171
        y: 0
        text: "Status"
        /* toggle */
        onClicked: {
            statusView.visible     = true
            settingsView.visible   = false
        }
    }

    Item {
        /* use id for access */
        id: statusView
        x: 0
        y: 50
        width: 640
        height: 430
        /* visible: true */

        Text {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            text: "status"
        }
    }

    Item {
        id: settingsView
        x: 0
        y: 50
        width: 640
        height: 430
        /* invisible */
        visible: false

        Text {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            text: "settings"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The most pragmatic one :-)